# Expanded Bottom Sheet Implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, bottom-sheet

I want to achieve the bottom Sheet as shown in the image given below
I want to know what the button is called which is circled in the given picture Is it Floating action button or a part of Bottom Sheet???

https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#expanding-bottom-sheet[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ7Zf.jpg)

Comment: Check this repo: https://github.com/HeyAlex/CornerSheet